# Change attribute in GCP Cloud scheduler

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-scheduler

I am trying to change some attributes dynamically, present in the Cloud Scheduler through the Cloud Functions.
Is is possible that I can write a Cloud Function in Python to change the attribute(API token) present in the cloud scheduler? Or any other way I can achieve this.
This can be done through gcloud shell using this script but I want to do this automation using a cronjob or code function.
gcloud scheduler jobs update pubsub my_job --update-attributes=["name"="test","limit"="1000"]

Comment: Are you looking for that: https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.jobs/patch

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I think this is a good solution. We can include the HTTP request to patch/update the Cloud Scheduler job in GCF function. You should definitely post this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to PATCH your scheduler, you can rely to that [API](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.jobs/patch). You have code sample in it, based on discovery API.

Comment: Thanks @guillaume blaquiere, this is what I was looking for.